# Zend Framework 1 - Message: SQLSTATE[HY093]: Invalid parameter number: no parameters were bound

Tags: php, mysql, zend-framework, zend-db, zend-db-table

**An error occurred
Application error
Exception information:
Message: SQLSTATE[HY093]: Invalid parameter number: no parameters were bound**

My Controller:

```
public function insertarAction() {
        $data = $this->getRequest()->getParams();
        // extract($data);


        if (isset($data['cod_domicilio'])) {

        $municipio = new Application_Model_DbTable_Municipios();
        $datos_municipio = $municipio->todosMunicipios();
        $datos_municipio['cod_municipio']=$data['cod_municipio'];

        $localidad = new Application_Model_DbTable_Localidades();
        $datos_localidad = $localidad->buscarLocalidad();

        $datos_municipio['cod_departamento']=$datos_localidad['codigo_departamento'];

        $rowMunicipio = $municipio->createRow();
        print_r($rowMunicipio);
        $rowMunicipio->save();
        }
}
```

Print R at time of capture:

```
    array (
  'controller' => 'beneficiarios',
  'action' => 'insertar',
  'module' => 'default',
  'codigo_beneficiario' => '',
  'codigo_ud' => '2007',
  'nombres' => 'lksakljsdlkjsd',
  'apellidos' => 'lkslkjslkjsd',
  'tipo_beneficiario' => 'estudiante',
  'tipo_documento' => 'CC',
  'numero_documento' => '10912919009',
  'genero' => 'M',
  'tipo_sangre' => 'o+',
  'fecha_nacimiento' => '2013-12-12',
  'huella_d' => 'Ajustes Base de Datos',
  'huella_i' => 'Ajustes Base de Datos',
  'telefono_fijo' => '9191919',
  'telefono_celular' => '9191919191',
  'email_personal' => 'info@hola.com',
  'email_institucional' => 'info@hola.com',
  'tipo_regimen_salud' => 'sub',
  'cod_entidad_salud' => '1',
  'nombre_contacto' => 'alkslkalkakl',
  'telefono_contacto' => '18918198',
  'cod_domicilio' => '1',
  'cod_pais' => '56',
)
```

The table:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `beneficiarios` (
  `codigo_beneficiario` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `codigo_ud` bigint(20) NOT NULL,
  `nombres` varchar(30) NOT NULL,
  `apellidos` varchar(30) NOT NULL,
  `genero` enum('M','F') NOT NULL,
  `tipo_documento` enum('CC','TI','CE','P') NOT NULL,
  `numero_documento` varchar(30) NOT NULL,
  `huella_i` blob NOT NULL,
  `huella_d` blob NOT NULL,
  `telefono_fijo` varchar(8) DEFAULT NULL,
  `telefono_celular` varchar(10) DEFAULT NULL,
  `email_personal` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `email_institucional` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  `tipo_sangre` enum('o+','o-','a+','a-','ab+','ab-','p','b+','b-') NOT NULL,
  `fecha_nacimiento` date NOT NULL,
  `tipo_regimen_salud` enum('sub','cont') NOT NULL,
  `nombre_contacto` varchar(60) NOT NULL,
  `telefono_contacto` varchar(10) NOT NULL,
  `cod_entidad_salud` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `cod_domicilio` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `cod_pais` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `tipo_beneficiario` enum('estudiante','docente','administrativo') NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`codigo_beneficiario`),
  KEY `fk_Beneficiario_Entidades_Salud1_idx` (`cod_entidad_salud`),
  KEY `fk_Beneficiario_Domicilios1_idx` (`cod_domicilio`),
  KEY `fk_Beneficiario_Paises1_idx` (`cod_pais`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=2 ;
```

I am inserting the data correctly but is showing me this error, the number of entered data is the same as in the table (22 data)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From this Example (Example 7) in the [ZF Manual](http://framework.zend.com/manual/1.12/en/zend.db.table.row.html#zend.db.table.row.write.insert), it seems you have to pass the data array, `$datos_municipio` to `createRow()` function .

`$rowMunicipio = $municipio->createRow($datos_municipio);`

OR

you have to set it as class properties like
`$datos_municipio->cod_departamento=$datos_localidad['codigo_departamento'];`

Comment: Additional i have insert data in other table :P